# Is there a way to reposition d3 pie charts after they are created by changing their origin?

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart, d3-force-directed

I have created a d3 pie chart using the standard way. However, my pie chart is nested inside a node of a force directed network graph.

I am able to create the pies normally and they display correctly within the nodes initially. However, they obviously don't update their positions on drag or tick. Is there a way to simply change the coordinates of the origin of the pie chart thereby adjusting the position of the arcs accordingly (i.e. preserving the radius, pie distribution, data...etc.)?

This is the code for the pie chart:

```
        const angleGenerator = d3.pie().value(d=>d.value);
        const data = angleGenerator(pieData)
        const arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(0)
            .outerRadius(params.radius)
        const arcs = node.selectAll('arc')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class','arc')
        arcs.append('path')
            .attr('fill', function(d,i){return color(i)})
            .attr('d',arc)
```

Tick function:

```
function ticked(){ //Add something here? }
```

Alternatively, I can retrieve the arc path 'd' attribute and modify that, but I'm not sure what to change. I can explore this option more if there isn't a simpler way. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? It will make it easier to find a valid solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If your arcs are inside `node` and the `node` group is being translated by the `tick` function, the pies should move as well. That said I second the comment above, please add a reproducible example.